# how could I make empty td has different background color then filled td ? td:empty not working with me

Tags: html

I tried to use `td:empty` but it's didn't work I don't know why

here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spoqx627/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define width to `td` :

```css
table{
  width:100%;
}
td{
  width: 100vw;
}
td:empty  {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>text1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>text3</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just that I can't see because I don't have the size.
Give it a try.

```
td:empty {
width: 10px;
background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not showing because the td height and width is not set so it is 0px therefore not visible.

```css
td:empty {
background-color: red;
height: 100px;
width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Hello there, I had an answer to your binary question, can you post it again?